# TableViewController cell not populating data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I can't figure out why the table view controller is not populating with `placeMarks.name` and `coordinates`.  The user taps a pin on the map and adds the location to the model. Where then it sent to the table view controller, however, it is not displaying the data from the model. Below is my code.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class PlaceList : NSObject  {

let locations: Places
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { return locations.coordinate }

init(point: Places) {
    self.locations = point
    super.init()
}

var title: String? {
    return locations.name
}

var subtitle: String? {
    return "(\(locations.coordinate.latitude), \(locations.coordinate.longitude))"
}

}

import  CoreLocation
import Foundation

class Places: NSObject {



var name: String
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(name: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.name = name
    self.coordinate = coordinate
}

}

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var placeModel: PlaceList?
var pointOfInterest: [Places] = []

var poi: [Places] = [] {
    didSet {
        pointOfInterest = poi

    }
}

//Creating mapview object
var mapView: MKMapView!
var geoCoder =  CLGeocoder()

//Initial cooridinate
var latitude = 43.136581
var longitude = -87.941101

var latitudeDelta = 0.3
var longitudeDelta = 0.3

//the object that determines the location
let placeManger = CLLocationManager()

//loading the map on the scene
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    mapView = MKMapView()
    view = mapView
    placeManger.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(true)

   navigationItem.title = "Travel Wishlist"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue

    placeManger.delegate = self
    placeManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapView.delegate = self

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBar
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBar

    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestrueRecongnizer)

    centerMapInInitialCoordinates()
    showPointsOfInterestInMap()


}

func showPointsOfInterestInMap() {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    for point in poi {
        let pin = PlaceList(point: point)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin as! MKAnnotation)
    }
}

func centerMapInInitialCoordinates() {
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latitudeDelta, longitudeDelta: longitudeDelta)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}

var tapGestrueRecongnizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loadPointOfInterests(recongnizer:)))
    return tapGesture

}

var rightBar: UIBarButtonItem  {

    let rightBarButton =
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Find a place to add",
                        style: .plain, target: self,
                        action: #selector(rightbarButton))
    rightBarButton.tintColor = .white

    return rightBarButton

}

var leftBar: UIBarButtonItem  {

    let leftBarButton =
        UIBarButtonItem(title:
            "Look up", style: .plain,
                       target: self, action: #selector(leftButton))
    leftBarButton.tintColor = .white

    return leftBarButton

}

@objc func leftButton(leftButton: UIBarButtonItem) {

    print("Left BarButton")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "place", sender: leftButton)
    addPlace()


}

@objc func rightbarButton(right: UIBarButtonItem) {

    addPlace()

}

func addPlace(){
   // mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    for point in pointOfInterest {
        let pin = PlaceList(point: point)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin as! MKAnnotation)

    }
    filterVisiblePOI()

}

func filterVisiblePOI() {
    let visibleAnnotations = self.mapView.annotations(in: self.mapView.visibleMapRect)
    var annotations = [PlaceList]()
    for visibleAnnotation in visibleAnnotations {
        if let annotation = visibleAnnotation as? PlaceList {
            annotations.append(annotation)
        }
    }

}


@objc func loadPointOfInterests(recongnizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let locationPoint = recongnizer.location(in: mapView)
    let cooridinate = mapView.convert(locationPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = cooridinate

    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: cooridinate.latitude, longitude: cooridinate.longitude)) {(placeMarks : [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) in
        if let placeLocation = placeMarks?[0] {

            if error == nil && (placeMarks?.count)! > 0 {

                let locationString = " \(placeLocation.name!)"
                annotation.coordinate = cooridinate
                annotation.title = locationString
                print(locationString)


            }
            for point in self.pointOfInterest {
                let pin = PlaceList(point: point)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(pin as! MKAnnotation)
                self.poi.append(point)
                print(point)
                print(self.pointOfInterest)
                print(pin)


            }


        }

    }

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Find a place to add"

}

private func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {

  //To Do


    }

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "place" {
        let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let detailViewControll = nav.topViewController as! VisitationTableViewController

        for point in pointOfInterest {
            let pin = PlaceList(point: point)
            mapView.addAnnotation(pin as! MKAnnotation)
            detailViewControll.poi = pointOfInterest



        }


    }


}

}

import Foundation
import UIKit

class VisitationTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var poi: [Places] = []



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

     super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let dissButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done
        , target: self, action: #selector(dismisController))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = dissButton
    dissButton.tintColor = .white

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.title = "Visited"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
    print("view didload")
    print(poi)

}

@objc func dismisController() {

    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return poi.count
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell", for: indexPath)

    let point = poi[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = point.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "(\(point.coordinate.latitude), \(point.coordinate.longitude))"

    return cell
}



}
```

Comment: Please don't post a giant pile of code and then simply say "why doesn't this work". Post just relevant code. Do some debugging. Narrow down the issue. Clearly explain what isn't working and where. Clearly explain what code you need help with.

Comment: The reason why I posted all the code is to make it easier to debug.

Comment: Don't think there's enough here (without description) to work out exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. how screens lead to each other). It *looks* as though you're adding points to an array (`poi[]`) in the MapViewController. The data source in the TableViewController is also called `poi[]`, but this is a different array. I cannot see how you are sync'ing the two - and maybe this is the problem? You do understand they're different (although they're named the same)?

Comment: @user2957494 it’s your job to debug before you post.

Answer (score 0):

You may need

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"place",sender:nil)
}
```

And make sure segue source is connected to the vc itself ( drag it from yellow roundec icon of mapVC inside IB )

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the code, tapping into the map didn't add any object to `pointOfInterest`, which you are making a loop on `loadPointOfInterests` to add an object to `poi` but its empty, so make sure to add a `Place` object in `poi`

In `VisitationTableViewController`, make sure to add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "locationCell")
}
```

Comment: I added a place object to poi and voila it worked. Thank you Abdalrahim.